# Typerror : 'list' object is not callable which the input is from .txt Python 3

Tags: python, text-processing, stop-words

I am trying to create a function that would remove stop-words inside a document. But instead, I got an error like this :

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Here is the code:

```
import re
def stopwords(text):
    reg = re.compile(r"\n")
    return reg.split(text)

file = open("stopwords.txt","r");
st = file.read()
stopwordz = stopwords(st)  #this is the error line

for word in stopwordz:
    raw1=raw1.replace(" "+word+" "," ")
    raw2=raw2.replace(" "+word+" "," ")
    raw3=raw3.replace(" "+word+" "," ")
    raw4=raw4.replace(" "+word+" "," ")
    raw5=raw5.replace(" "+word+" "," ")
```

The error occurred on stopwordz variable line. I was trying to use [] instead of () but still can't solve the issue. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks before.~

Comment: may be you could just do `stopwordz = st.splitlines()` directly as `splitlines()` uses `\n` as line boundaries

Comment: Could not reproduce the error - the code runs without error until `raw1=raw1...` complaining correct,that `raw1` is not defined. Could you please post the exact error message?

Comment: Thanks @SudhirBastakoti. It works perfectly.

Comment: I don't include all the codes @SpghttCd, sorry for that.